# Bullet chart using Kendo-UI with angular 2

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I have a bullet chart which I can display but I don't know how to add plot ranges.

Could someone please provide a sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

`<kendo-chart-value-axis-item [min]="0" [max]="80 [plotBands]="PlotBandValues">
</kendo-chart-value-axis-item>`

TS

`PlotBandValues = [{
    "color": "#44aa44",
    "from": 48,
    "opacity": 1,
    "to": 57
}]`

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14936375)

Comment: That is a complete answer